# Run frontend web controller method in console controller method for cronjob yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, php-5.6

I have a index method in **frontend/controllers/FollowupcandidteclientController**
where i am returning some values after running this controller method.

below is my code(just for reference)

class FollowupcandidteclientController extends \yii\web\Controller
{

```
    public function actionIndex()
     {

     $a=2;
     $b=3;
     $c=$a + $b;
     return $c;

 }
```

}

I have set cronjob with the controller name CronjobController in console/controllers/CronjobController.

In this I have a method called runcron().

I want to run the followupcandidateclient/index in this **cronjob controller** **runcron** method

Below is my code for cronjob

**namespace console\controllers;**

**use Yii;**

**use yii\console\Controller;**

Class CronjobController extends Controller
{

```
public function actionRuncron(){
```

here this action should run **index.php?r=followupcandidateclient/index** when the cronjob is executed

```
      }
```

**}**

**?>**

**It would be great and very thankfull if any body helps me on this issue.
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: please somebody help me on this its very critical

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortest way for you is just `curl` it.

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "yourdomain/index.php?r=followupcandidateclient/index"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);  

// use $output if needed
```

If you can't access it in cron via internet, then you can start PHP server like this (with appropriate port number):

```
$ cd /path/to/your/index.php/
$ PHP -S localhost:8002
```

Then in curl request you can use `localhost:8002` instead of `yourdomain`